# Mapping from $Re(z)\leq0$ onto the disk $|z|\leq1$

Tags: complex-analysis

How am I supposed to do it? I really have no idea at all.

Comment: Are you sure about the non-strict inequalities?

Comment: Well, that's the question in my homework. But maybe my teacher typed wrongly.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation?wprov=sfti1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*: Recall the Möbius transformation
$$
f\colon z\mapsto\frac{z+1}{z-1}
$$
maps the open left half plane onto the open unit disc.  This almost does what you want: $f(\{z\in\mathbb{C}\mid\operatorname{Re}z\leq 0\})=\overline{D}(0,1)-\{1\}$.  Can you think of some $g\colon\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $g\circ f$ would do?